# How to find all controls in Gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a `gridview`  which contains controls like `checkbox dropdownlist textbox` etc.. These controls are in `TemplateField` and some are in `updatepanel` in gridview. There is a `EditTemplateField` which has some controls and a `button`. When grid is in edit mode, Now I have to find all controls in this EditTemplateField in `button click event`. I know that this can be done using foreach loop but don't know how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the grid EditIndex to find the row that contains the controls that are in edit mode.  From there you can get the control using the control ID.

```
TextBox txtItem = (TextBox)Grid1.Rows[Grid1.EditIndex].FindControl("txtItem");
```

To find all controls then try this:

```
foreach(Control c in Grid1.Rows[Grid1.EditIndex].Controls)
{
    // do stuff in here.

}
```

If you have container controls in the row, and need to find things inside of them, then you need do do something to recurse down into their controls.

I don't understand though why you would need to loop though the controls, usually the controls in the edit template will be fixed, and you know what they are so accessing them directly with Findcontrol is the way to go.

Comment: +1 @Chris Mullins: I have to find all controls, not only textbox. So I need to run a loop.

Comment: I updated my answer for you.  Also the answer by James has a good method of getting just the controls of a certain type.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean in code you can do it like this:

```
foreach ( GridViewRow row in MyGridView.Rows )
{
    TextBox myTextBox = (TextBox)row.FindControl("myTextBox");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a nifty utility method. It's recursive so it will find nested stuff e.g.

```
var listOfControls = Utility.FindControlsOfType<TextBox>(yourGridRow);
```

If you don't know the exact type of the nested controls, use **FindControlsOfType<WebControl>** instead.

```
public static class Utility
{    
    public static List<T> FindControlsOfType<T>(Control ctlRoot)
    {
        List<T> controlsFound = new List<T>();

        if (typeof(T).IsInstanceOfType(ctlRoot))
            controlsFound.Add((T)(object)ctlRoot);

        foreach (Control ctlTemp in ctlRoot.Controls)
        {
            controlsFound.AddRange(FindControlsOfType<T>(ctlTemp));
        }

        return controlsFound;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take the generated html using Firebug and using http://jsfiddle.net you can include jquery and play with the html.

Add the event handler to the edit button like

For example

```
function edit(this)
{
   var textboxID = $(this).parent().find("[id$='textBoxId']");
}
```